# Variable as an id when changing src of an image

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with changing the source of several images with a loop. I have several images each with its own id and a loop cycles through these ids. Below an excerpt of my code.

With a fixed id like in line 3 it works but when using a variable like in line 4 it does not work., although imgName is exacly what I use in line 3 (I checked that with the alert).

```
for (var i in data.users) {
    var imgName = "\"#" + data.users[i].name + "\"";
    $("#Licht_Wohnzimmer").attr('src',"Img\\Pic_" + data.users[i].status + ".gif");
    //$(imgName).attr('src',"Img\\Pic_" + data.users[i].status + ".gif");
    //alert(imgName);
}
```

Can anyone give me hint what my problem is?

Comment: Get rid of the escaped quotes on imgName.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `data.users[i].name` equals the string `foobar`,

`var imgName = "\"#" + data.users[i].name + "\"";` will result to the string `"#foobar"` (the double quotes being part of the string itself).

So `$(imgName)` will be resolved to `$("\"#foobar\"")`: the two surrounding double quotes have to be removed (i.e. not to be added):

`var imgName = "#" + data.users[i].name;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgName = data.users[i].name;
$('#' + imgName).attr('src',"Img\\Pic_" + data.users[i].status + ".gif");
```

Comment: *"Can anyone give me hint what my problem is?"* So what's the problem? You posted code without an **explanation** which is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You get the name of the image and then change the src property like this :

```
for (var i in data.users) {
   var imgName = data.users[i].name;
   imgName.src = "Img\\Pic_" + data.users[i].status + ".gif";
}
```